# Not able to Run Shell Script

Tags: java, cygwin

I am trying to run an shell script from my Windows OS using Cygwin. When i run from command prompt it works fine as i go insight **C:\cygwin\bin** and Run **sh my_script.sh**.

When i am trying this through code getting following error

```
C:\Java\jdk1.6\bin>java CmdProcessBuilder
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\cygwin\bi
n\my_script.sh": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:459)
        at CmdProcessBuilder.main(CmdProcessBuilder.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32
 application
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
        ... 1 more
```

Following is the Code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
     throws InterruptedException,IOException
  {
    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
    command.add(System.getenv("cygwin") +"\\bin\\"+"sh my_script.sh");

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

    final Process process = builder.start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println("Program terminated!");
  }
```

When i am trying **cd cygwin\bin\sh my_script.sh** from command prompt it is not executing giving error msg **The system cannot find the path specified.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have better luck using `Runtime.exec` like this:

```
String fs = System.getProperty("file.separator");
String command = System.getenv("cygwin") + fs + "bin" + fs + "sh my_script.sh";

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

It is also good practice to avoid using platform-dependent strings in your paths as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing your command with

```
./cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/my_script.sh
```

? If you want to go from what you have, you probably need to replace your command with

```
command.add(System.getenv("cygwin") +"\\\\bin\\\\"+"sh my_script.sh");
```

to execute

```
  C:\cygwin\\bin\\my_script.sh
```

which is how windows styled paths are used in cygwin.

Comment: C:\cygwin\bin>sh my_script.sh This is the command which i m running at cmd prompt

Comment: Have you tried `./cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/my_script.sh` through cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I note about your construction is that you might not be building the command string correctly.  Reading the ProcessBuilder docs (hadn't used this one before), you build a process command with a List of Strings as you are doing, but the first string is the command, the others are the arguments.  The way you are constructing the comamnd:

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add(System.getenv("cygwin") + fs + "bin" + fs + "sh " + "my_script.sh"); 

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

appears to create a command name that ***includes*** the script name.  Change the call to:

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add(System.getenv("cygwin") + fs + "bin" + fs + "sh ");
command.add("my_script.sh"); 

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

and check the error.  Then, check if the issue that the c:\cygwin\bin\sh.exe is not being found or that the script itself is not being found.  You mention attempting a **cd** that is failing, so where is the **my_script.sh** script located relative to the java class files?  When you invoke the **sh** command it may not be able to locate the **my_script.sh** file because the working directory may not be where you think it is.

One thing you might try is to determine where **sh.exe** thinks it is running.  From your Java code you should be able to invoke the shell with this:

```
  List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
  String fs = System.getProperty("file.separator");
  command.add(System.getenv("cygwin") + fs + "bin" + fs + "sh");
  command.add("-c");
  command.add("pwd");
```

The output of this should be the directory that the shell command thinks it is running from.  If this isn't where the actual **my_script.sh** is located, you may need to fully path to the the script itself (as an example path in cygwin format)

```
  command.add(System.getenv("cygwin") + fs + "bin" + fs + "sh");
  command.add("/usr/local/scripts/my_script.sh");
```

This is where I'd start debugging.